# Taskwarrior - task recurring on the last work day of each month

Tags: taskwarrior

In *Taskwarrior*, is it possible to create a recurring task that would recur on the last work day of each month?

In the docs, there's:

- *`eoww` - Local date for the end of the work week, Friday night, with time 23:59:59*
- *`eom`, `eocm` - Local date for the last day of the current month, with time 23:59:59*

But I need a mix of the two.

As a workaround, I currently use `eom-2d` (2 days before end of current month), which is usually OK, but that's not optimal.

Comment: Please ask TaskWarrior usage questions on SuperUser